# I am trying to make my switch case loop back again if they get the default

Tags: java, loops

```
    //Choice of choosing a dog or a cat

     String pet = input.next();

    switch (pet.charAt(0)) {
        case 'a' -> {
            System.out.println("What is your dog's name? ");
            String dogsName = input.next();
            System.out.println("Your Character's Name is: " + playerName + "\nYour Pet's Name is: " + dogsName);
        }
        case 'b' -> {
            System.out.println("What is your cat's name? ");
            String catsName = input.next();
            System.out.println("Character Name: " + playerName + "\nPet Name: " + catsName);
        }
        default -> System.out.println("That is not a valid option. Please choose again.");
    }

   input.close();

}
```

I can't find a loop to use that would bring it back to case a and repeatedly until the user answers using one of the choices, Any help would be awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using `do while` loop is a simple way to solve it.

I used a variable `repeat` to check, If I need to ask for the input again or not

Also, note that now even If I add another case(say `case 'c'`) I don't need to modify condition for my `do while` loop

```java
boolean repeat;
do {
    String pet = input.next();
    repeat = false;
    switch (pet.charAt(0)) {
        case 'a' -> {
            System.out.println("What is your dog's name? ");
            String dogsName = input.next();
            System.out.println("Your Character's Name is: " + playerName + "\nYour Pet's Name is: " + dogsName);
        }
        case 'b'-> {
            System.out.println("What is your cat's name? ");
            String catsName = input.next();
            System.out.println("Character Name: " + playerName + "\nPet Name: " + catsName);
        }
        default: System.out.println("That is not a valid option. Please choose again.");
        repeat = true;
    }
} while(repeat);
input.close();
```

Comment: This solution also spams the default, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To loop the entire switch-case section, you can try putting it in a do-while loop. As for the condition to use with the do-while block you could try:-
`do {...}while(pet.charAt(0)!='a' || pet.charAt(0)!='b');`

I am providing you with a possible solution below:-

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("    Welcome To The Choices Game...    ");
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: " );

    String playerName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is " + playerName + "'s" + " favorite pet?");
    System.out.println("a. Dog \nb. Cat");

    //Choice of choosing a dog or a cat

    do{
     String pet = input.next();

    switch (pet.charAt(0)) {
        case 'a' -> {
            System.out.println("What is your dog's name? ");
            String dogsName = input.next();
            System.out.println("Your Character's Name is: " + playerName + "\nYour Pet's Name is: " + dogsName);
            break;}
        case 'b' -> {
            System.out.println("What is your cat's name? ");
            String catsName = input.next();
            System.out.println("Character Name: " + playerName + "\nPet Name: " + catsName);
            break;}
        default -> System.out.println("That is not a valid option. Please choose again.");
    }
   
}while(pet.charAt(0)!='a' && pet.charAt(0)!='b');

  input.close();
```

}

Comment: I would set a boolean flag "isWrongAnswer" which is set to true in the default case and set to false in the correct cases.
This way you dont check for 'a' or 'b' redundantly.

Comment: Yes, that is another feasible solution. Instead of checking for the character entered, you could check for the value of a boolean flag.

Comment: Thank you, but when I used this solution, it kept spamming default over and over again.

Comment: I have edited the code. There was a logical error in the while condition of the do-while block. This should run fine.

Comment: Thanks again!! But for some reason it keeps having the same problem:/

Comment: This is because there is no 'break' statement in your switch-case code. Thus, you are having a 'fall through' to the default case even if the user inputs 'a' or 'b'. Add a 'break' statement after cases 'a' and 'b' to avoid this issue. It worked fine for me with the 'break' statements inserted at the end of every case.

Comment: I've still been trying and the same problem keeps coming up with me, even after I tried using the breaks in the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Looping is good solution but you can also use the Recessive methods in java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
        System.out.println("    Welcome To The Choices Game...    ");
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: " );
    
        String playerName = input.nextLine();
    
        System.out.println("What is " + playerName + "'s" + " favorite pet?");
        System.out.println("a. Dog \nb. Cat");
    
        //Choice of choosing a dog or a cat
    
        method();
   
    
      input.close();
    
 }

public void method()
{

         String pet = input.next();
    
        switch (pet.charAt(0)) {
            case 'a' -> {
                System.out.println("What is your dog's name? ");
                String dogsName = input.next();
                System.out.println("Your Character's Name is: " + playerName + "\nYour Pet's Name is: " + dogsName);
            }
            case 'b' -> {
                System.out.println("What is your cat's name? ");
                String catsName = input.next();
                System.out.println("Character Name: " + playerName + "\nPet Name: " + catsName);
            }
            default -> System.out.println("That is not a valid option. Please choose again.");
            method();
        }
       
}
```