# I am trying to make my switch case loop back again if they get the user gets the default

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

I can't find a loop to use that would bring it back to the beginning of the switch case and repeatedly until the user answers using one of the choices, Any help would be awesome! Thanks. (I have also tried using a do-while loop that someone suggested but it just seems to spam the default.) ((which I left in the code))

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("    Welcome To The Choices Game...    ");
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");

    String playerName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is " + playerName + "'s" + " favorite pet?");
    System.out.println("a. Dog \nb. Cat");

    //Choice of choosing a dog or a cat
    String pet = input.next();
    do {


        switch (pet.charAt(0)) {
            case 'a' -> {
                System.out.println("What is your dog's name? ");
                String dogsName = input.next();
                System.out.println("Your Character's Name is: " + playerName + "\nYour Pet's Name is: " + dogsName);
                break;
            }
            case 'b' -> {
                System.out.println("What is your cat's name? ");
                String catsName = input.next();
                System.out.println("Character Name: " + playerName + "\nPet Name: " + catsName);
                break;
            }
            default -> System.out.println("That is not a valid option. Please choose again.");
        }

    } while (pet.charAt(0) != 'a' && pet.charAt(0) != 'b');

    input.close();

}
```

Comment: Okay, so what goes wrong when you try the code that you have?

Comment: Whenever I type in another char or int besides "a" or "b", it goes to a stack overflow printing out "That is not a valid option. Please choose again."

Comment: And what did you expect to happen instead? I assume, that the user is prompted for input again. Now, look at the code closely.  What is the part of your code that is supposed to ask the user for the `"a"` or `"b"` input? How many times will that happen? How many times *should* it happen? Is it inside the loop, or outside the loop? *should* it be inside the loop, or outside the loop?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to make my switch case loop back again if they get the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63444755/i-am-trying-to-make-my-switch-case-loop-back-again-if-they-get-the-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the input for Cat/Dog (option a or option b) inside the do loop so that after wrong input code can ask for updated input. As below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("    Welcome To The Choices Game...    ");
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");

        String playerName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("What is " + playerName + "'s" + " favorite pet?");
        System.out.println("a. Dog \nb. Cat");

        // Here is change in code
        String pet = null;
        do {
            // Choice of choosing a dog or a cat
            // Here is change in code
            pet = input.next();
            switch (pet.charAt(0)) {
            case 'a': {
                System.out.println("What is your dog's name? ");
                String dogsName = input.next();
                System.out.println("Your Character's Name is: " + playerName + "\nYour Pet's Name is: " + dogsName);
                break;
            }
            case 'b': {
                System.out.println("What is your cat's name? ");
                String catsName = input.next();
                System.out.println("Character Name: " + playerName + "\nPet Name: " + catsName);
                break;
            }
            default: {
                System.out.println("That is not a valid option. Please choose again.");
            }
            }

        } while (pet.charAt(0) != 'a' && pet.charAt(0) != 'b');

        input.close();

    }
```